# How to get 20 screenshots from a video with tile or mosiac effect ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get 20(Will take screens at 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%,.., of the video) screenshot which will be arranged in a single image like this [Link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20take%20multiple%20screenshots%20to%20an%20image%20(tile%2C%20mosaic))

I found this command but it is taking screenshot based on frames like 1000 I want to get evenly distributed 20 screenshots of the entire video

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i movie.avi -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1000)),scale=320:240,tile=2x3" out.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select filter does not have access to the movie duration, so you'll have to run

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -c copy -an -f null -
```

to get total frame count and adjust the select interval accordingly.

Comment: I've tried this but i am getting this error `Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in st
ream 0: 360 >= 360
`

Comment: Doesn't matter. All you need to care about, is the `frame=` value at the end of execution.

Comment: and i am using webm file

Comment: Ok got it Thanks